# libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) in Android

Tags: android, libc

I am trying to debug a crash on Huawei devices. The app crashes on startup and here is what i get in the log cat:

```
05-23 15:41:43.183 12647-12710/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) in tid 12710 (Cache.runLoop())
05-23 15:41:43.285 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-23 15:41:43.285 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/NXT-L29/HWNXT:6.0/HUAWEINXT-L29/C185B180:user/release-keys'
05-23 15:41:43.285 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
05-23 15:41:43.285 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
05-23 15:41:43.285 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG: pid: 12647, tid: 12710, name: Cache.runLoop()  >>> mypackagename <<<
05-23 15:41:43.285 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 0 (SI_USER), fault addr 0x7f
05-23 15:41:43.309 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000007f9a61a000  x1   0000000032c43800  x2   0000007f9a64d000  x3   0000007f9a64d728
05-23 15:41:43.309 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000032d3c000  x5   0000007f8231cbcc  x6   0000000032d3c008  x7   0000000000002288
05-23 15:41:43.309 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000032d4395c  x9   000000007144af64  x10  000000000000000a  x11  0000000000001bb6
05-23 15:41:43.309 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000000000005322  x13  0000000032c4387c  x14  000000007144aee0  x15  000000007144af5c
05-23 15:41:43.309 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000000000020000  x17  0000000000000000  x18  0000000000030006  x19  0000000000000002
05-23 15:41:43.309 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG:     x20  000000000000007f  x21  0000007f98ecbd88  x22  0000000000000001  x23  0000000000000006
05-23 15:41:43.309 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000000000000000  x25  0000007f8231cbc8  x26  0000007f93d43400  x27  0000007f8176cd08
05-23 15:41:43.309 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000000000000003  x29  0000007f8176cba0  x30  0000007f9a61a9b8
05-23 15:41:43.309 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007f8176cba0  pc   0000007f9a4e967c  pstate 0000000000000000
05-23 15:41:43.310 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
05-23 15:41:43.310 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00000000001b267c  /system/lib64/libart.so (offset 0x253000)
05-23 15:41:43.310 3203-3203/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00000000002e39b4  /system/lib64/libart.so (offset 0x253000)
```